# Basis of $Hom(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over $F$. Let $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ be a basis of $V$ and $w_{1},...,w_{n}$ be a basis of $W$. Find a related basis of $Hom(V,W)$ and give its dimension.

I'm not really sure what a basis of $Hom(V,W)$ would be, as it is a set of linear maps and not of vectors.

My initial idea was to write some $v \in V$ that maps into an arbitrary vector in $W$:
Let $T \in Hom(V,W)$ such that some $w_{j} \in rangeT$. Then,  $\exists v_{i} \in V$ such that $T(v_{i}) = w_{j}$

$w_{j} = T(v_{i1}) + ... + T(v_{in})$

I don't know how to grasp the concept of $Hom(V,W)$ from this.

I know, however, that $Hom(V,W)$ can be described as the set of matrices of $n\times n$ dimension with entries in $F$. Could I use matrices as "vectors" for the basis of $Hom(V,W)$. If yes, how is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that for vector spaces $V$ and $W$, $\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$ is also a vector space?

Comment: In other words: "it is a set of linear maps and not of vectors" is necessarily wrong, since the exercise is precisely about this set of *vectors*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern algebra, a vector space (over a field $F$) is *any* set $H$ that has been equipped with an addition operation $+: H \times H \to H$ and a scalar multiplication operation $\cdot: F \times H \to H$, that together satisfy the usual axioms. From this point of view, $\hom(V, W)$ is considered a vector space, provided that suitable addition and scalar multiplication operations have been defined for it. And indeed, it is standard that for linear maps $f, g: V \to W$, we define $f+g$ to be the linear map that takes $v \in V$ to $f(v) + g(v) \in W$ [one should verify that $f + g$ is indeed linear], and for $r \in F$, we define $r \cdot f$ to be the linear map that takes $v \in V$ to $rf(v) \in W$. In this way, we have defined addition and scalar multiplication operations for $\hom(V, W)$, and once we are satisfied that these satisfy the vector space axioms, then $\hom(V, W)$ may be considered a vector space.

So now that you know what it means to say $\hom(V, W)$ is a vector space, it makes sense to ask what how one might construct a basis for it, in terms of a given basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ for $V$ and a basis $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ for $W$. (By the way, in your question you assume that $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension $n$, but this assumption is an unimportant distraction.)

Your last idea is a good one, but where you say $\hom(V, W)$ can be described as a set of matrices, it's important to understand what exactly this means. Let me first turn this around a bit with an example. Let us take our vector space $V$ to be $F^m$, where the elements of $F^m$ are written as columns of length $m$ whose entries are elements of $F$. This has a standard basis, consisting of column vectors $e_i$, $i$ running from $1$ to $m$, where the i-th entry of $e_i$ is $1$ and the other entries are $0$. Similarly, let us take $W$ to be $F^n$, with its standard basis.

Any $n \times m$ matrix $M$ ($n$ rows, $m$ columns) with entries in $F$ gives a linear map $F^m \to F^n$, taking a vector $v$ with column entries $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ to the vector $w$ with entries $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ defined by $w_i = \sum_{j=1}^m M_{ij} v_j$. And every linear map $f: F^m \to F^n$ comes from such a matrix. Indeed, the i-th column of this matrix will be precisely the column vector $f(e_i) \in W$, where again $e_i$ refers to the i-th standard basis vector.

So if you have bases to work with, then you can freely pass back and forth between linear maps $f: V \to W$, and matrix representations of linear maps, but mind you, these matrix representations will depend on which bases you choose for $V$ and $W$ at the outset.

In any case, the set of $n \times m$ matrices, considered as a vector space, has a basis consisting of $mn$ many elements $e_{ij}$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$ and $j$ ranges from $1$ to $m$. Namely, $e_{ij}$ is the matrix whose entry in row $i$ and column $j$ is $1$, and whose remaining entries are empty. Considered as a linear map, $e_{ij}$ takes the standard basis element $e_j$ of $V$ to the vector $e_i$ of $W$, and takes every other standard basis element of $V$ to the zero vector.

So back to your problem, and using the above discussion as hints, you should be able to describe, given a vector space $V$ with given basis $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ and a vector space $W$ with given basis $w_1, \ldots, w_n$, a collection of linear maps $f_{ij}: V \to W$ that serve as a basis of $\hom(V, W)$. For this, it is useful to know that a linear map $f$ is completely determined by its values $f(v_i)$ at a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ (so you should specify the linear maps $f_{ij}$ in terms of their values at basis elements).

There are lots of little details to check through, but this should get you started.